# Any ideas for a hardware to do AM and FM modulation?

Tags: signal-processing, intel-fpga, matlab, amplitude-modulation, python

I'm trying to do some signal processing (AM/FM Modulation) for signals from 0 - 60kHz. Any recommendations for hardware? Preferably something I can use MATLAB with (or Python) as I'll most likely be dealing with complex signals (or modifying the original signal).

EDIT: I've looked at Altera boards and while they do have the potential to do the calculation, I'm worried it'll be a bit challenging to learn VHDL within the timeframe.

Comment: Welcome to the site. As it stands this question is very open ended, and it isn't really clear what this project is. For the people who can answer, its probably very trivial, so you need to explain more about your specific problem.

Comment: The title asks about hardware, but then the question talks about Matlab and Python.  Go away until you've figured out what one thing you really want to ask about.

Comment: the EE SE is more for *advice* on existing designs, people here won't design thins for you, for that I'd recommend a proper forum like the eevblog.

Comment: @sam Just too bad, what a pity behavior of such a discussion board. Also too many down vote addict.

Comment: EE SE isn't really a discussion board, EE SE is where people come who *already* have a design ad need *advice* on how it operates or why it doesn't do what it's supposed to, there's an awful lot of people who've asked thinly veiled homework questions and many of the users over time just switch off when they hear things like "recommendation" or "can you suggest..." or "how do I do X?". Those sort of questions are better fielded to a real forum like the eevblog where people more freely give their own opinions and *ideas*, EE SE is basically an interactive encyclopedia.

Comment: Exactly what Sam said. @Bianca, you have to realize that you're asking people not only to help others with a specific problem that they describe well enough in their question, but also spend the time to do a proper dialog to collaboratively come up with ideas. That's really by no means what this site was designed for. If you want that, a chat, or a classical forum is much much better suited. And:Downvotes are **good**,as they are the only way to keep the average quality on here *answerable*. It's not inherently impolite to downvote a question – many are objectively bad or impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Many sound cards nowadays have sampling frequencies up to 196kHz. That would be more than sufficient for your purposes. Not sure if Matlab can hookup to an audio device easily, but Python certainly can.